# How do I analyze these two sets of data

Tags: statistical-significance, dataset, ordinal-data

I am doing a research study on self efficacy and birth month (when children enter school, if they are oldest in class or youngest).
I have each of the participants scores on their self efficacy scale (rated on a 14 point likert scale) and I have ranked their birth months (starting with Sept = 1, Oct = 2, etc.).

I am wondering how I can analyze this data to find statistical significance, variance, etc.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 4):

First, a 14 point Likert scale is quite unusual. I don't think I've ever seen one. Is this the sum of two 7 point questions?

Second, given that you are actually interested not in birth month, per se, but in time in school, why not use that? Beware that, by using birth month as a proxy for this, you are assuming that all the children in your study go to schools with the same cut-off. This isn't necessarily the case.  In NY city, for instance, public schools have one cutoff and private and parochial schools have another (last I checked, these were Dec. 1 and Aug 1, but my memory might be off).

Third With that assumption, birth month is usable as an IV. You could do either ordinal logistic regression or possibly ordinary least squares regression. 14 points is a lot for ordinal but not enough really for OLS.  In situations like this, I usually run *both* models, then I compare the predictions. If they are similar, I use the simpler model (in this case, OLS).

Comment: +1 in general, but I want to second the suggestion to use age or time-in-school over some coded version of the birth month too. Unless I'm missing something domain specific, I don't see any upside and a lot downside to using the birth month....

Comment: Is 14 different categories really not enough to treat the variable as continuous in OLS regression and satisfy all the assumptions?

Comment: @PatrickCoulombe I think you have to run the model and check the residuals.